# Can I still migrate current project to support null-safety while some of the dependencies not support it yet?

Tags: flutter, dart, dart-null-safety

It would take too long to wait until all dependencies to support the null-safety. So I am thinking not to wait for them. I wonder if I can do or should do that.

Answer (score 0):

First requirement in https://dart.dev/null-safety/migration-guide (a Google-provided document, and they should know):

1. Wait for the packages that you depend on to migrate.

So, wait.

You can help speed it up by helping them migrate (post an issue first, or look for any existing issue to watch).  Pull requests welcome!